# Paperclip: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have below configurations:
`initializers/paperclip.rb`

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ':rails_root/public/system/attachments/:id/:basename:style.:extension'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:use_timestamp] = false
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3.amazonaws.com'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_region] = 'us-west-2'
Paperclip::HttpUrlProxyAdapter.register
```

`environment.rb`

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: name,
      access_key_id: key,
      secret_access_key: key,
      s3_region: 'us-west-2',
      s3_protocol: :https,
      url: ":s3_domain_url"
    }
  }
```

`Gems Used:`

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.8'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.3'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'
```

The read operation is working fine but getting error(`Aws::S3::Errors::PermanentRedirect - The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.:`) on uploading the file to bucket.